# HTTP Query for Address validation to USPS API using apache camel

Tags: java, xmlhttprequest, apache-camel, usps

I have written code using camel to invoke USPS address validaton api.
I tried all the possible way to send the request but its getting encoded and request fails. while endpoint of USPS API expecting xml - string , due to encoding of request xml endpoint unable to parse the request and getting below parsing error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Number>80040B19</Number>
  <Description>XML Syntax Error: Please check the XML request to see if it can be parsed.</Description>
  <Source>USPSCOM::DoAuth</Source>
</Error>
```

Request gets encoded like  when checked in wireshark:

> /ShippingAPITest.dll?API=Verify&XML=%3CAddressValidateRequest%20USERID=%5C%22705LBEYO2631%5C%22%3E%3CAddress%3E%3CAddress1%3E%3C/Address1%3E%3CAddress2%3E6406%20Ivy%20Lane%3C/Address2%3E%3CCity%3EGreenbelt%3C/City%3E%3CState%3EMD%3C/State%3E%3CZip5%3E?%3C/Zip5%3E%3CZip4%3E?%3C/Zip4%3E%3C/Address%3E%3C/AddressValidateRequest%3E HTTP/1.1

While its expected format is:

```
API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest%20USERID=\"705LBEYO2631\"><Address><Address1></Address1><Address2>6406 Ivy Lane</Address2><City>Greenbelt</City><State>MD</State><Zip5></Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>
```

Route file: route.xml

```
<route id="UspsAddressValidationRoute" >
  <from id="ProcessAddressValidationRequest" uri="direct:processUspsAddressValidation" />
  <to id="PrepareAddressValidationRequest" uri="bean:serviceUspsAddressValidationProcessor?method=constructAddressValidationRequest" />
  <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
    <constant>GET</constant>
  </setHeader>
  <to id="SendAddressValidationRequestToUsps" uri="{{usps.soapEndpoint}}"/>  
  <to id="ProcessAddressValidationUspsResponse" uri="bean:serviceUspsAddressValidationProcessor?method=processUspsAddressValidationResponse" />
</route>
```

usps.soapEndpoint = http://testing.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll
ServiceUspsAddressValidationProcessor --> ConstructAddressValidationRequest()

Method has below snippets of code:

```
exchange.setProperty(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "GET");
//exchange.setProperty(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml");
exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY,  getHttpQuery(serviceUspsAddressValidationRequest.getUspsAddress()));
exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, getHttpQuery(serviceUspsAddressValidationRequest.getUspsAddress()));
exchange.getIn().setBody("");

...

public String getHttpQuery(UspsAddress uspsAddress){
  String validateUrl = "API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID=\\\"%s\\\"><Address><Address1>%s</Address1><Address2>%s</Address2><City>%s</City><State>%s</State><Zip5>%s</Zip5><Zip4>%s</Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>";
  String userid = "XXXXXXXXXXXX" ;  
  String httpQuery = String.format(validateUrl, userid,
  uspsAddress.getAddress1(),
  uspsAddress.get_Address2(),
  uspsAddress.getCity(),
  uspsAddress.getState(),
  uspsAddress.getZip(),
  uspsAddress.getZipPlus4());
  //httpQuery = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(httpQuery);
  System.out.println("\n****************httpQuery ****************\n" + httpQuery);
  return httpQuery;
}
```